# sed to modify a line and add a commented version of the orginal line

Tags: awk, sed, replace

I have a file containing multiple rows of the following format

```
[Site "https://sitename.com/8994DX1"]
[Date "1999.11.04"]
...
[Site "https://sitename.com/678489s"]
[Date "2000.12.04"]
...
[Site "https://sitename.com/788Xxz"]
[Date "2020.12.04"]
```

I want to prepend the original site line with a semi-colon. I want to add a new dummy site line, which has the same sitename every time.

```
;[Site "https://sitename.com/8994DX1"]
[Site "https://sitename.com/12345"]
[Date "1999.11.04"]
...
;[Site "https://sitename.com/678489s"]
[Site "https://sitename.com/12345"]
[Date "2000.12.04"]
...
;[Site "https://sitename.com/788Xxz"]
[Site "https://sitename.com/12345"]
[Date "2020.12.04"]
```

In other words, I want to make the original unique sitename a comment, and in a new unvarying sitename.

I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675833/how-can-i-duplicate-a-line-and-search-and-replace-on-the-duplicate-with-sed) which is close, but I haven't managed to modify it to do what I need.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: pointing us to a different question doesn't tell us what you've tried nor does it give us any idea what modifications you've attempted; please update the question with the actual `sed` code you've tried along with the (wrong) result generated by said code

Comment: I assume your desired output is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `sed` command should do the trick:

```
sed -i.bak '
/^\[Site /!b
s/^/;/
a\
[Site "https://sitename.com/12345"]
' file
```